# type the NAME of a TextBox into a TextBox and then be able to retrieve the contents of the named TextBox

Tags: vb.net

for example, I want to declare the textbox based on what I write in the box. if I write textbox1. if I type textbox2.text then it will be textbox2.text

```
Dim txt As TextBox = TextBox2.Text.ToString
Dim txt As String = TextBox2.Text
```

none of the methods is valid

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  Why are you declaring the same variable twice?  Why are you calling `ToString` on a string?  What specifically are you trying to do and what isn't working as expected?

Comment: You cannot declare a control with a name that is resolved at runtime. I guess this is one of the issues which can be solved with a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`.

Comment: if I type textbox1.text in the box, then my textbox will be textbox1.text (ie the textbox written in my box)

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your verbiage, although confusing, makes it seem like you want to type the NAME of a TextBox into a TextBox and then be able to retrieve the contents of the named TextBox. If that's correct, you're probably looking for [Controls.Find()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) with the recurse option:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim txtBoxName As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim
    If txtBoxName.Length > 0 Then
        Dim ctl As Control = Me.Controls.Find(txtBoxName, True).FirstOrDefault
        If Not IsNothing(ctl) AndAlso TypeOf (ctl) Is TextBox Then
            Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(ctl, TextBox)
            ' ... do something with "tb" ...
            Dim value As String = tb.Text
            MessageBox.Show(value)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Control not found, or incorrect type!")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```